# Convert request Function to Generic type

Tags: ios, generics, swift3

I am trying to convert my below fetch request code from core data to generic type.

```
let request = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@ AND password == %@ AND type == %@", "admin", "admin", "admin")
let fetchReq : NSFetchRequest = UserRegistration.fetchRequest()
fetchReq.predicate = request
let adminDetail :[UserRegistration] = DatabaseEngine.fetch(fetchRequest: fetchReq)!
```

Converted so far:

```
extension UIViewController{
    class func getData<T: NSManagedObject>(req: NSPredicate) -> T{
        let fetchReq : NSFetchRequest = T.fetchRequest()
        fetchReq.predicate = req
        return DatabaseEngine.fetch(fetchRequest: fetchReq as! NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>)! as! T

    }
}
```

---

DatabaseEngine.fetch function.

```
static func fetch (fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T> = NSFetchRequest(), context:NSManagedObjectContext = kApplicationDelegate.managedObjectContext) -> [T]? {

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: typeName(some:T.self)
        , in:context)
    // Configure Fetch Request
    fetchRequest.entity = entity
    do {
        return try  context.fetch(fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as? [T]
    } catch {

        //let fetchError = error as NSError
        // return nil

    }
    return nil
}
```

But no results any more. Anybody help me to convert this code with few explaining lines. Ans will be appreciated sure.

Comment: Why would you implement this function as an extension of `UIViewController`? Moreover, your types seem to be mismatched. In your first implementation, `DatabaseEngine.fetch` returns an array, while in your generic implementation, it returns a single object. However, without seeing the implementation of `DatabaseEngine.fetch`, it is really hard to say anything certain.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, yes it will return the array exactly, please tell if you can modify this extension and its type what it could be.

Comment: Then just make the return type `[T]`. However, as I have already said, without seeing the definition of `DatabaseEngine.fetch`, I cannot give an exact answer. Btw force unwrapping the return value and force casting both seem to be bad ideas for a function unless you are 100% sure, the result will never be `nil` (in which case, defining the function to return an optional makes no sense in the first place).

Comment: @DávidPásztor, please see DatabaseEngine.fetch func.

Comment: Core Data is quite generic already. Rather than making a generic more generic I recommend a protocol and a protocol extension (unrelated to `UIViewController`) constrained to `NSManagedObject` with static methods which all `NSManagedObject` subclasses can adopt. And you are making the smart error handling (`throw`ing errors and returning non-optional objects on success) worse by turning errors into optionals. Make `getData` *can throw* and pass-through the thrown error.

Comment: @vadian, i am pleased to see an better example to get more info.

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my comment I recommend to use a protocol with extension for example

```
protocol Fetchable
{
    associatedtype FetchableType: NSManagedObject = Self
    
    static var entityName : String { get }
    static var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext { get }
    static func objects(for predicate: NSPredicate?) throws -> [FetchableType]
}

extension Fetchable where Self : NSManagedObject
{
    static var entityName : String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
    
    static var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext {
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    
    static func objects(for predicate: NSPredicate?) throws -> [FetchableType]
    {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<FetchableType>(entityName: entityName)
        request.predicate = predicate
        return try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
    }
}
```

Change `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext` to the reference to your managed object context.

Make all `NSManagedObject` subclasses adopt `Fetchable`. There is no extra code  needed in the subclasses.

Now you can get the data with

```
do {
   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: ...
   let objects = try MyEntity.objects(for: predicate)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

That's all, `objects` are `[MyEntity]` without any type casting and always non-optional on success.

The protocol is easily extendable by default sorting descriptors, sorting directions etc.

Comment: Vadian, thanks for your ans and explanation, its great.

Comment: getting error `does not confirm to protocol` when i tried to adopt `Fetchable` protocol to entity class.

Comment: My bad, it was a typo in the declaration (`mnaged` without a). Fixed.

Comment: Yes i got it and one more i corrected, thanks anyway :)

Comment: this is not compatible from ios 9 version, please suggest to make it compatible, until not useful at all.

Comment: *not useful at all*?? Your question does not contain nor mention iOS 9 code at all.  in iOS 9 you have to get the managed object context the traditional way via the property in `AppDelegate` (assuming the default Core Data stack is used).

Comment: Okay, please suggest for ios 9 here.

Comment: Replace `let request = NSFetchRequest<FetchableType>(entityName: entityName)` with `let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:entityName)` and `return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext` with `return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext`

Comment: replacing this `let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:entityName)` leads `Ambiguous reference to member 'entityName'` this error.

Comment: I don't know if you can use Swift 3 generic fetch requests in iOS 9. If yes don't replace the fetch request line.

Comment: Using xcode 9.0, then obvious higher version of swift it has.

Comment: OK, then you need only to change the line to get the managed object context.

Comment: Yes all good, but when i clear the project this removes the `NSManagedObject` subclass `Fetchable` from there.

Comment: Above solution doesnt work... because still error `doesnt conform to procotol Fetchable` happens...

Comment: @vadian I have seen an edit. Everything seem to be fine now.