# How to cast T.Type for an NSFetchRequest?

Tags: swift, generics, core-data

I've got a method signature: `func fetch<T>(_ model: T.Type, predicate: NSPredicate?, sorted: Sorted?, completion: (([T]) -> Void)) where T: Storable` and I would like to use `model` in an NSFetchRequest.

In this situation, `extension NSManagedObject: Storable {}` is used and the `Storable` protocol has some basic CRUD method definitions inside.

I've tried:

- casting `T` to `NSManagedObject`, however this caused operator precedence errors. `(T as! NSManagedObject)` didn't work, therefore.
- just using `NSFetchRequest<T>()` but the compiler tells me that `T does not conform to NSFetchRequestResult`.
- `where T: Storable, NSManagedObject` but that would mean having to update my protocol to have implementation details and I don't want to go there.
- `(model as! NSManagedObject).fetchRequest()` but `Cast from 'T.Type' to unrelated type 'NSManagedObject' always fails`

What I'm trying to achieve is basically: I want to be able to `fetch(User.self, ...)` with the current signature of the method if possible.

Comment: I'd recommend to use a protocol extension, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037860/convert-request-function-to-generic-type/46038865#46038865)

Comment: @vadian Interesting, instead of Fetchable, I'd use my own `Storable` protocol for extension, right?

Comment: @vadian And isn't the associatedtype in your linked answer tightly coupling it to `NSManagedObject` that way?

Comment: It's just an example how to use a protocol extension with associated types. Yes, the associated type is always the `NSManagedObject` subclass. It's quite impossible to make the already generic types like `NSFetchRequest` *more* generic

Comment: I happened to strumble upon a way to do this, so I answered my own question, but thank you very much for your help, @vadian!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to cast the `T.Type` to `NSManagedObject.Type` to have the type, and then call `.fetchRequest()` on that.

```
func fetch<T: Storable>(_ model: T.Type, predicate: NSPredicate?, sorted: Sorted?, completion: (([T]) -> Void)) {
    guard let managedObjectType = model as? NSManagedObject.Type else {
        return
    }

    let fetchRequest = managedObjectType.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    ...
}
```