# Error creating NSFetchRequest<T> in generic function

Tags: swift, generics, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I want a generic function to return a CoreData object:

```
func getManagedObject<T: NSManagedObject>(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> T
{
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest()  // ERROR
    ...
}
```

But I get `Cannot assign value of type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>' to type 'NSFetchRequest<T>`.

I've tried adding a `where`, but doesn't help. This only adds a warning `Redundant conformance constraint 'T': 'NSFetchRequestResult'`:

```
func getEntity<T: NSManagedObject>(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> T where T:NSFetchRequestResult
```

What does work is:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = T.fetchRequest()
```

But why didn't my first attempt work?

Comment: `T` as a generic constrained to `NSManagedObject` and `T` as a generic constrained to `NSFetchRequestResult` are two different types and not interchangeable.

Comment: @vadian Is that (also) why `where` failed?

Comment: Yes, a more suitable way is a protocol with associated types like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037860/convert-request-function-to-generic-type/46038865#46038865