# How do I define generic typealias for Swift to return specific types of objects?

Tags: swift

Here is my simple class:

```
class PersistentStoreCoordinatorMock: Storageable {
    var objects = [T]() // here I need to define return array
    func findAll<T: NSManagedObject>(of type: T.Type, predicate: NSPredicate) -> [T] {
        findAllWasCalled = true
        return objects //here I need to return this when that function was called
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'd prefer a protocol with associated types, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037860/convert-request-function-to-generic-type/46038865#46038865

Comment: I don’t understand. `T` is not defined at class-scope, but that’s where it needs to be, if you’re going to refer to it there. (Maybe figure out what it is, because it is surely not a `T`. I pity the fool who has to work with something named `T`. At least capitalize the name of the property; i.e. `PersistentStoreCoordinatorMock<Object: NSManagedObject>` and `[Object]()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, *`T` is not defined at class-scope*. You need to specify the generic type with the class declaration so it can be used across your class.
Try this:

```swift
class PersistentStoreCoordinatorMock<T: NSManagedObject>: Storageable {
    var objects = [T]() // here I need to define return array
    func findAll(of type: T.Type, predicate: NSPredicate) -> [T] {
        findAllWasCalled = true
        return objects //here I need to return this when that function was called
    }
}
```