# Core Data: Generic class function to return object

Tags: swift, core-data

I have several classes of base type NSManagedObject and each of them contains a class function to return the first object of a given context. Here's an example:

```
public class Car: NSManagedObject {
    class func first(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Car? {
        let fetchRequest = Car.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        let results = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return results?.first
    }
}
```

Instead of writing this function for every subclass I'd like to put a generic version as an extension to NSManagedObject. I've tried this:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    class func first(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self? {
        let fetchRequest = Self.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        let results = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return results?.first
    }
}
```

But this gives a "Type of expression is ambigous without more context" error. How can this be done?

Comment: Use a protocol extension as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037860/convert-request-function-to-generic-type/46038865#46038865)

Comment: @vadian: While I think the concept of protocol extensions is interesting, it doesn't solve the issue in my example, you still get the same error.

Comment: Does it work with `let results = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Self]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context.fetch()` returns `[Any]`, but you can conditionally cast it to the expected type `[Self]`:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    class func first(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self? {
        let fetchRequest = Self.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        let results = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Self]
        return results?.first
    }
}
```

Or with a real do/try/catch for better diagnostics in the error case:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    class func first(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self? {
        let fetchRequest = Self.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        do {
            let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Self]
            return results?.first
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```