# FetchRequest results doesn't want to convert to an Array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I simply have an extension:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    class func all(sortedBy: String?, ascending: Bool, predicate: NSPredicate?, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [NSManagedObject] {
        let request = fetchRequest()
        if let predicate = predicate {
            request.predicate = predicate
        }
        if let sortedBy = sortedBy {
            request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: sortedBy, ascending: ascending)]
        }
            do {
                return try context.fetch(request) //Cannot convert return expression of type '[any NSFetchRequestResult]' to return type '[NSManagedObject]'
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("❌ Core Data Fetch All Error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                return []
            }
    }
}
```

I want to use it like this for example:

```
Person.all(sortedBy: nil, ascending: true, predicate: nil, context: context)
Home.all(sortedBy: "streer", ascending: true, predicate: nil, context: context)
```

Implementation of Fetchable protocol:

[image]

```
protocol Fetchable {
    associatedtype FetchableType: NSManagedObject = Self
    func delete()
}

extension Fetchable where Self: NSManagedObject, FetchableType == Self {

    func delete() {}
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037860/convert-request-function-to-generic-type/46038865#46038865) answer. It shows a (more generic) protocol based solution.

Comment: I agree with @vadian because even if this is fixable you still would have to cast the result, `let all = Person.all(sortedBy: nil, ascending: true, predicate: nil, context: context) as? [Person]`

Comment: I try to apply generic solution and if it works I will post an answer here

Comment: Bartłomiej - could you install a spell-checker in your browser? Stack Overflow isn't a chatroom - please use real words, and check spelling before you publish.

Comment: @vadian I have added Fetchable type, but it still display error for example `Type Category does not conform to protocol Fetchable`. Why?

Comment: Delete `, FetchableType == Self`, I edited the linked answer.